# and example of a continuous function only in $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, functions

Can someone suggest an example of a function $f$ that is continuous in every $[a,b]$ but not in all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You say "in every $[a,b]$", which means "simultaneously continuous in the infinitely many overlapping closed intervals, anywhere in $\Bbb{R}$", but in comments to an answer, you do **not** mean this.  Are you sure you mean "in every $[a,b]$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function. Take $c\in\Bbb R$. Then $f$ is continuous in $[c-1,c+1]$ and therefore it is continuous at $c$.

Comment: But I learn that if a function is continuous in [a,b] it doesn't mean it's continuous in all R

Comment: for example 1/x it's continuous in [1,100] but not in R

Comment: $1/x$ is not continuous **in every** $[a,b],$ or did you not intend to write "for every" in your question?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 2$ on $[a,b]$, and if $x$ is not in $[a,b]$, $f(x) =1$ if $x$ is rational, $0$ if not. Then $f$ is continuous only on $]a,b[$. You can modify it a bit so it becomes continuous at $a$ and $b$ but not at other points.